# Basic RF signal amplifier

Tags: amplifier, antenna, radio, frequency-response

I made an 8 Mhz shortened antenna with a length of 12.3cm and wire diameter of 2mm by a 220uH bobin at the bottom. The transmitter and the receiver circuits have the same antenna configurations. The transmitting of a wave file succeeded. Receiver circuit has a LM386 audio amplifier, so i was sure to have done this transferring correctly, but one thing made me confused at this point. Why must i be so close to the transmitter so about 1 meter away for this experiment. After all, i recognized that the LM386 amplifier has a very tight frequency scale. I decided to amplify the whole 8 Mhz signal processing with an extern amplifier like below. First, i would amplify the RF signal, after that the audio signal. Well, the problem is the following one: When i amplify the voltage, will the current keep the default value or better say, how can i amplify the current to any value i want to set on? The circuit below is an op amp equivalent one, i think so. I researched for a time and have seen that voltage feedback is also desired, because of the voltage follower setting for keeping the same wave as in the input, so in output amplified. As i said, the circuit below is a production of non-tested imagination with dummy values. Can you tell me what more important might be? The voltage or current amplification for this 8 Mhz antenna transmission? The input signal has an amplitude of 1 mV. The output voltage is about 60 mV. I have a gain ratio of 60. Will be the transmitting therefore better than before?

[image: The imaginary circuit]

[image: oscillation with gain]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you tell me what more important might be? The voltage or current amplification for this 8 Mhz antenna transmission?

What is most important is neither your voltage amplification, nor your current amplification, but the matching of your amplifier with your antenna, and the power you can deliver to the antenna.

For example, if you have a common emitter amplifier with 1 k\$\Omega\$ output impedance, and you feed the output of that amplifier directly to a 50 \$\Omega\$ antenna, the results will be very disappointing, even though a common emitter amplifier can have both good voltage gain and good current gain.

That is not to say that a common emitter amplifier cannot be used in radio frequency applications. However, it almost always needs a *matching network* (or in some cases an RF transformer) to match the amplifier's output impedance to the antenna's impedance or to the impedance of a transmission line (such as a coax cable or twin-lead) connecting the amplifier to the antenna.

Alternatively, a common-base amplifier, which has high voltage gain, but virtually no current gain, can also be used to amplify radio frequency signals. As can a common-collector amplifier, which has high current gain, but virtually no voltage gain.  The trick is matching the amplifier impedance with the antenna impedance so that maximum *power* can be transferred. (Or, in the case of multi-stage amplifiers, to match the output impedance of one stage with the input impedance of the next).

Incidentally, the input impedance of a common-base amplifier is generally low, i.e. near the impedance of many antennas. For that reason it is often used to amplify signals coming *from* an antenna. The output impedance of a common collector amplifier is also "low", and for that reason is often used to amplify signals going *into* an antenna. However, in both cases, it would be serendipitous for the amplifier impedances to match the antenna impedances exactly. So, impedance matching networks are frequently an important part of radio frequency amplifiers. LC impedance matching networks tend to be "narrow band". This works well if the frequency of interest is precisely known in advance. However, for a general purpose "wide-band" radio frequency amplifier, a radio frequency transformer to match impedances will likely be used instead.